# Chrome App Input function simplify

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am writing a chrome app for logging a uses time spent on projects, 
I have a set of push buttons that allow them to just use 4 quick buttons with preset times on each one eg 7.5min , 15min, 1 hour, 4 hour.

This is to encourage users to submit project time as close to real time as possible while making it easier rather than opening a webapp.

This bit of code basically just adds the defined time to the input box "hourTime" using the 4 buttons.

Is there a way for me not to call 4 separate functions for each button and simplify my code? i am not really a JS guru so i am sure i could improve this.

Stackoverflow help would be much appreciated.

```
//adds 7.5 minutes to the input    
function addbt1(){
  var b1 = ((1/8)+ Number(document.getElementById("hourTime").value));
  b1 = b1.toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById("hourTime").value = b1;
}
document.querySelector("#add1Funct").addEventListener("click", addbt1);
//adds 15 minutes to the input  
function addbt2(){
  var b2 = ((1/4)+ Number(document.getElementById("hourTime").value));
  b2 = b2.toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById("hourTime").value = b2;
}
document.querySelector("#add2Funct").addEventListener("click", addbt2);
//adds 1 hour to the input  
function addbt3(){
  var b3 = ((1)+ Number(document.getElementById("hourTime").value));
  b3 = b3.toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById("hourTime").value = b3;
}
document.querySelector("#add3Funct").addEventListener("click", addbt3);
//adds 4 hour to the input 
function addbt4(){
  var b4 = ((1*4)+ Number(document.getElementById("hourTime").value));
  b4 = b4.toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById("hourTime").value = b4;
}
document.querySelector("#add4Funct").addEventListener("click", addbt4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept `argument` for the handler-function which can be difference for different elements event is attached on!

```js
function addbt(val) { //accept argument as `val`
  document.getElementById("hourTime").value = (val + Number(document.getElementById("hourTime").value)).toFixed(3);
}
document.querySelector("#add1Funct").addEventListener("click", function() {
  addbt((1 / 8));
});
document.querySelector("#add2Funct").addEventListener("click", function() {
  addbt((1 / 4));
});
document.querySelector("#add3Funct").addEventListener("click", function() {
  addbt((1));
});
document.querySelector("#add4Funct").addEventListener("click", function() {
  addbt((1 * 4));
});
```

Comment: Mate, that is perfection, that cuts the code in half and is much more logical. Thanks